# Determine $DISPLAY socket name on OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, display, remote, xorg

I'm looking to do something that's a little odd. I'm SSH'ing *from* a server *to* a Snow Leopard client to start an X11 data display process. In other words, SSH's X11 forwarding isn't what I want.

I can do:

```
client$ echo $DISPLAY
/tmp/launch-SOMETHING/org.x:0
client$ ls -l $DISPLAY
srwx------  1 myuser  wheel  0 Dec  9 15:47 /tmp/launch-SOMETHING/org.x:0
```

And, when I do:

```
server$ ssh myuser@client
client$ export DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-SOMETHING/org.x:0
client$ xterm
```

I happily get my xterm.

What I need, then, is some way to find out the correct value for $DISPLAY in my ssh session. From what I've read, $DISPLAY is set by launchd, but I haven't found any way to see that value.

If it matters, I know that when my process connects from $server to $client, $client will logged in to the terminal as the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer (gonna wait a few days to flag it!) but seems promising:

First, make a script on $client, say, save_display.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $DISPLAY > /path/to/saved_disp
```

Next, make a LaunchAgent .plist for it, save it in ~/Library/LaunchAgents. Have it start with an interval of 60 seconds or something.

Finally, load it *in the Aqua session*:

launchctl load -S Aqua ~/Library/LaunchAgents/my.display.saver.plist

If you just load it normally, $DISPLAY won't be set and your file will be empty.

Then,

```
server$ ssh myuser@client
client$ export DISPLAY=`cat /path/to/saved_disp`
client$ xterm
```

and success.

Seems to keep working across reboots. I'm pretty happy with it.